# finding variables of one side of the equation given cos and tan

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

These are actually two questions, but they seem to be similar to one another.

> 1) Find $d$, $e$, $f$, and $g$ such that  $4\cos(x)\cos(2x)\cos(4x) = \cos(dx) + \cos(ex) + \cos(fx) + \cos(gx)$. **$d$, $e$, $f$, and $g$ are positive integers**.

I substituted some formulas for $\cos(2x)$ and $\cos(4x)$. After expanding, I got: $7\cos^4(x)-6\cos^2(x)+\sin^4(x)$.

I'm not sure how to get rid of the $\sin^4(x)$ and, after doing that, find $d$, $e$, $f$, and $g$. Any hints?

> 2) Find $h$, $i$, $j$, and $k$ such that $ \tan 7.5^\circ =\sqrt{h}+\sqrt{i}-\sqrt{j}-\sqrt{k} $

All I have so far is that $\tan 7.5^\circ = 0.1317$ radians. Other than that, I am not sure where to go from there. Any hints on this one as well?

Comment: Do you know radian measure for angles? $7.5$° is $\dfrac\pi{24}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** for (1): you can use the expansion of
$$\cos(A+B)+\cos(A-B)$$
to write $2\cos x\cos2x$ as a sum of two cosine terms.  Then multiplying by $2\cos4x$ gives you a product of two cosine terms, twice, and you can use the same idea again.

**Hint** for (2): let $\alpha=\tan(7.5^\circ)$.  Use the double angle formula to find $\tan15^\circ$ in terms of $\alpha$.  Use a sum or difference formula to find the actual value of $\tan15^\circ$.  Solve a quadratic to find $\alpha$.  Bit of work simplifying surds.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use the expansion of $cos(A+B) + cos(A-B)$ to yield $2cos 4x$. Can you further explain?

Comment: Also, $2cos x * cos 2x$ yields $cos (3x) + cos (-x)$

Comment: For number (2), if I did the quadratic correctly, it would be: $((2-\sqrt{3})tan^2 a + 2tan a - (2-\sqrt{3})$

Comment: You should memorise the expansion of $\cos(A+B)$, it is very important ;-)

Comment: I see now. Currently, I have $16cos^4 x - 16cos^2 x + 2 + cos(3x) + cos(-x)$. How can I further simplify that?

Comment: Sorry but I do not at all understand how you got that.  Please follow the suggestions in my answer carefully.

Comment: I used $cos (2x+2x)$ to get $16cos^4 x - 16cos^2 x +2$

Comment: Multiplying by $2cos4x$ is also the same as $2cos(2x+2x)$, where I had $2cos(2x)cos(2x)-2sin(2x)sin(2x)$. $sin(2x) = 2sinxcosx$, then that gives us $cos(2x)cos(2x)-2(2sinxcosx)(2sinxcosx)$, expanding and simplifying gives me $2cos(2x+2x) = 16cos^4 x -16cos^2 x+2$.

Comment: $$\eqalign{4\cos x\cos2x\cos4x &= 2(2\cos x\cos2x)\cos4x \cr &= 2(\cos3x+\cos x)\cos4x \cr &= 2\cos3x\cos4x+2\cos x\cos4x \cr &= \cos\frac72x+\cos\frac12x+\cos\frac52x+\cos\frac32x\ .\cr}$$

Comment: d, e, f, and g are supposed to be integers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20047/discussion-between-mathy-person-and-david).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

For question **a**, as David commented, start with the right hand side using $$\cos(A) + \cos(B)=2 \cos(\frac{A+B}{2})\cos(\frac{A-B}{2})$$ So $$\cos(dx) + \cos(ex)=2 \cos(\frac{d+e}{2}x)\cos(\frac{d-e}{2}x)$$ $$\cos(fx) + \cos(gx)=2 \cos(\frac{f+g}{2}x)\cos(\frac{f-g}{2}x)$$ So, if  $$A=\cos(dx) + \cos(ex)+\cos(fx) + \cos(gx)$$ then $$A=4 \cos(\frac{d+e}{2}x)\cos(\frac{d-e}{2}x)\cos(\frac{f+g}{2}x)\cos(\frac{f-g}{2}x)$$

I am sure that you can take from here.